# Syntax for check boxes - customer error message

Tags: cognito-forms

What is the syntax for a custom error message when the user does not tick ALL the checkboxes?

E.g. I have three check boxes that must be agreed to before the form can be submitted:

> I agree to the following:
>
> - Checkbox - A
> - Checkbox - B
> - Checkbox - C

I want to show a Custom Error message ("Please check the above") when any one of `A` or `B` or `C` is not ticked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set this up using the following calculation in the 'Show Custom Error' on the 'I agree to the following:' Choice field.

```
=(IAgreeToTheFollowing.Count() < 3)
```

This will check to see if your Choice field has 3 of its options selected. If not then the error message 'Please check the above' will be displayed.

I have also added the test template, that I used to set up this calculation. You can copy the form to your Organization, and view the build page to review how the calculation has been set up.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoFormsTestAccount/CheckboxCustomErrorMessage